# How to create two date formats using XSLT

Tags: xml, date, xslt

The input XML is:

```
<elems>
  <elem dataType="java.lang.String">N</elem>
  <elem dataType="java.lang.Date"/>2015-12-29</elem>
  <elem dataType="java.lang.String">
    <TEST>
      <TEST1>
        <TEST2>
          <ACT>CREATE</ACT>
          <START_DATE>2015-12-19</START_DATE>
          <END_DATE>2015-12-29</END_DATE>
        </TEST2>
        </TEST1>
    </TEST>
  </elem>
  <elem dataType="java.lang.String">
    <TEST>
      <TEST1>
        <TEST2>
          <ACT>CREATE</ACT>
          <START_DATE>2015-12-19</START_DATE>
          <END_DATE>2015-12-29</END_DATE>
        </TEST2>
      </TEST1>
    </TEST>
  </elem>
</elems>
```

I need a XSLT which can transform this XML, and change the date format for START_DATE & END_DATE not any other dates present in the XML.

Intended output:

```
<elems>
  <elem dataType="java.lang.String">N</elem>
  <elem dataType="java.lang.Date"/>2015-12-29</elem>
  <elem dataType="java.lang.String">
    <TEST>
      <TEST1>
        <TEST2>
          <ACT>CREATE</ACT>
          <START_DATE>19-DEC-2015</START_DATE>
          <END_DATE>29-DEC-2015</END_DATE>
        </TEST2>
        </TEST1>
    </TEST>
  </elem>
  <elem dataType="java.lang.String">
    <TEST>
      <TEST1>
        <TEST2>
          <ACT>CREATE</ACT>
          <START_DATE>19-DEC-2015</START_DATE>
          <END_DATE>29-DEC-2015</END_DATE>
        </TEST2>
      </TEST1>
    </TEST>
  </elem>
</elems>
```

Any lead on this will be really helpfull.

Comment: Please state if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Good if we can have XSLT 1.0. And also if there are no 
<START_DATE>2015-12-19</START_DATE>
          <END_DATE>2015-12-29</END_DATE>
Then it should not change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="START_DATE/text() | END_DATE/text()">
    <xsl:call-template name="reformat-date">
        <xsl:with-param name="date" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="reformat-date">
    <xsl:param name="date"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after($date, '-'), '-')" />
    <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="substring-before(substring-after($date, '-'), '-')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="substring('JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC', 3 * ($m - 1) + 1, 3)"/>
    <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($date, 1, 4)" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is good. But there is a problem in it. If the <START_DATE></START_DATE> & <END_DATE></END_DATE> comes empty in the input then it adds `--` in it. Which should not be the case.

Comment: @Sammy, if you don't want to do anything with empty elements then change `<xsl:template match="START_DATE | END_DATE">` to `<xsl:template match="START_DATE[normalize-space()] | END_DATE[normalize-space()]">`, that way the transformation is only applied to elements with some non white space content.

Comment: @Sammy You said "*if there are no <START_DATE>...*". You didn't say it can be empty. Anyway, I have edited my answer.